# moviemodeapp script on my local web page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am getting wired issue in my local server web page on firefox browser, when i am open site in firefox browser, the one script is adds in `<head>` tag, please see blow
[image]

I have also disabled all firefox addon but still the script is seeing in source code,
[image]

I have search on google, but not found about the issue, i am very stuck.
anyone can help me, what is this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Looks like malware from something you installed on your computer. The website says that it's a plugin to add features to video viewing on your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's Firefox, but it could be some sort of malware or something that has gotten into your system. For whatever reson, it's injecting javascript into each browser session.

Does this happen for every single site or just this particular site you are working on?

I can't access most of these links, but looks like there might be something [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=d.moviemodeapp&oq=d.moviemodeapp&aqs=chrome..69i57.4729j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=moviemodeapp+malware)

Comment: thank you for help, i found program `Movie mode` software in program. i have uninstalled then working fine..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are including a lot of 3rd party javascript files, which are capable of inserting additional `<script>` tags into your page. Try removing all `<script>` tags / javascript from your page temporarily, and see if it still appears.

Answer (score 0):

there are many malicious scripts/addons out there that add themselves to your browsers regardless of what page you visit.
i would suggest running an adware scan, you can get a free anti adware app here:
https://www.malwarebytes.org/